# Add logo and button to react navbar

Tags: reactjs

I am using the react-site-nav package in a react application with typescript. I am having trouble styling the navbar.

I want the navbar to have a logo on the left end and a button on the right end, and the links to pages should be in the middle. I can't figure out how to add a logo to the left end of the package navbar.

I used flexbox and kept the items in a row, but when I put the `SiteNav` element in a flexbox div that has padding, the drop-down menu of ContentGroup gets displaced by the padding. I don't know how to offset the padding for the `ContentGroup`. Changing the style of the content group by subtracting the padding is what I think could be my solution.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

[link to navbar package] (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-site-nav)

```
<SiteNav>
        // add an image that is at the start of the navbar

        <ContentGroup title="About" height="200">
         Some text 1
        </ContentGroup>
        <ContentGroup title="Contact" height="200">
         Some text 2
        </ContentGroup>

        // add a button that is at the end of the navbar
</SiteNav>
```

Comment: Can you post a stackblitz of your code. I can help you out then!

Comment: @DOZBORNE Thanks so much for trying to help!! I created a code sandbox for it and tried to replicate the code and the problem I faced. [https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-tsznb9?file=/src/App.tsx](link to code sandbox) The navbar package however isn't working properly here but I feel like you might get a better understanding of the problem. I can make a github repo and send that to you otherwise.

Comment: I'll look at it soon!

Comment: Hmm, yeah that's odd. Stackblitz is not actually recognizing it exists really. If you could push up to a repo, that would be helpful!